# Downgrading from dnn 9.1.0 Professional edition to dnn 9.1.0 Community edition

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, move, downgrade, dotnetnuke-9

I have a website on DNN framework **v. 09.01.00 (512)** professional edition. I want to downgrade it to DNN framework **v. 09.01.00 (512)** community edition. I removed the evoq related dlls from the bin folder of my website directory and managed to get the website running, however the DnnPersonaBar is all messed up. I cannot navigate between the pages nor can I add new pages or edit them. I am facing some licensing issues. I also went through this [StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751975/dotnetnuke-best-way-to-move-from-professional-to-community-edition).

But it was not of much help. Waiting for a solution.

Comment: Never try it, but try run CE on PE database (Use backup)

Answer (score 0):

After brainstorming for a considerable amount of time, I figured out that PersonaBar was using a license key which was getting stored in database table PersonaBarMenu. I referred to the PersonaBarMenu table of DNN 9.0.1 Community version and changed the controllers which used Evoq content. This fixed my issue and downgrading works perfectly fine for me.